# Does x% color gamut in consumer electronics implies x% of sRGB in the CIE 1931 (x, y) coordinate system?

Tags: display

Specifications of desktop monitors and laptop screens often list a single percentage as the color gamut. From my limited understanding, a meaningful color gamut definition requires at least two things:

The coordinate system of the color space, e.g.:

- CIE 1931 (x, y)
- CIE 1976 (u', v')

And the area covered by the primaries of the color space, e.g.:

- Rec. 709 / sRGB
- Adobe RGB

For example, one monitor says that it is 85% CIE 1976 and 72% CIE 1931 (color space unspecified). Another one says that it is 100% sRGB and 75% Adobe RGB (coordinates system unspecified).

In the absence of a proper specification, is it understood that a color gamut percentage refers to a comparison with sRGB in CIE 1931?